CKEditor5 plugin: Error when trying to insert a div at a specific position
I am working on a CKEditor5 plugin that inserts a div with custom class at a specific position in the document. However, I am encountering an error when trying to insert the div at the start of a block element's parent.
Here is the relevant part of my code:


import { Plugin, Command } from "ckeditor5/src/core";
import { Collection } from "ckeditor5/src/utils";
import { addListToDropdown, createDropdown, Model } from "ckeditor5/src/ui";

class InsertDivCommand extends Command {
  execute({ value }) {
    const editor = this.editor;
    const model = editor.model;

    model.change((writer) => {
      const selection = model.document.selection;

      if (selection.isCollapsed) {
        console.log("selection is collapsed");
        return;
      }

      const range = selection.getFirstRange();

      if (!range) {
        console.log("no range");
        return;
      }

      const blockElement = range.start.parent;

      if (!blockElement.is("element", "paragraph")) {
        console.log("blockElement is not a paragraph");
        return;
      }

      // Create a new div element.
      const divElement = writer.createElement("div", { divClass: value });
      console.log("blockElement.name:", blockElement.name);
      console.log("blockElement.parent:", blockElement.parent);
      console.log(
        "blockElement.parent.name:",
        blockElement.parent && blockElement.parent.name
      );
      // Insert the div at the same level as the paragraph.
      if (
        blockElement.parent &&
        blockElement.parent !== model.document.getRoot()
      ) {
        writer.insert(
          writer.createPositionAt(blockElement.parent, 0),
          divElement
        );
      } else {
        if (
          blockElement.name === "$block" ||
          blockElement.name === "paragraph" ||
          blockElement.name === "$root"
        ) {
          const root = model.document.getRoot();
          if (root.childCount > 0) {
            const rootFirstChild = root.getChild(0);
            if (
              rootFirstChild &&
              model.schema.checkChild(rootFirstChild, "div")
            ) {
              try {
                writer.insert(
                  writer.createPositionAt(rootFirstChild, 0),
                  divElement
                );
              } catch (error) {
                console.log("error", error);
                console.trace(); // Print a stack trace
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      // Move the content of the paragraph into the div.
      // Ensure that the range does not contain elements that are not allowed inside a div.
      const allowedRange = model.schema.getNearestSelectionRange(
        range,
        "forward"
      );
      if (allowedRange) {
        writer.move(allowedRange, writer.createPositionAt(divElement, "end"));
      }

      // Remove the original paragraph if it's empty.
      if (!blockElement.childCount) {
        writer.remove(blockElement);
      }
    });
  }

  refresh() {
    const model = this.editor.model;
    const selection = model.document.selection;

    this.isEnabled = !selection.isCollapsed;
  }
}

export default class StyleBlockDropdownPlugin extends Plugin {
  init() {
    const editor = this.editor;
    const t = editor.t;

    editor.model.schema.extend("$block", { allowIn: "div" });
    editor.model.schema.register("div", {
      isBlock: true,
      allowWhere: "$block",
      allowContentOf: "$block",
    });
    editor.model.schema.extend("paragraph", { allowIn: "div" });
    editor.model.schema.extend("paragraph", { allowChildren: ["div"] });
    editor.model.schema.extend("$root", { allowIn: "div" });
    editor.conversion.for("upcast").elementToElement({
      view: "div",
      model: "div",
    });
    editor.conversion.for("dataDowncast").elementToElement({
      model: "div",
      view: (modelElement, { writer }) => {
        return writer.createContainerElement("div", {
          class: modelElement.getAttribute("divClass"),
        });
      },
    });

    editor.conversion.for("editingDowncast").elementToElement({
      model: "div",
      view: (modelElement, { writer }) => {
        return writer.createContainerElement("div", {
          class: modelElement.getAttribute("divClass"),
        });
      },
    });

    editor.commands.add("insertDiv", new InsertDivCommand(editor));

    editor.ui.componentFactory.add("myDropdownBlock", (locale) => {
      const dropdownView = createDropdown(locale);

      addListToDropdown(dropdownView, this._createDropdownItems());

      dropdownView.buttonView.set({
        label: t("Style blokowe"),
        tooltip: true,
        withText: true,
      });

      this.listenTo(dropdownView, "execute", (evt) => {
        editor.execute("insertDiv", { value: evt.source.commandParam });
        editor.editing.view.focus();
      });

      return dropdownView;
    });

    let toolbar = editor.config.get("toolbar");

    if (Array.isArray(toolbar)) {
      if (toolbar.indexOf("myDropdownBlock") === -1) {
        editor.config.set("toolbar", [...toolbar, "myDropdownBlock"]);
      }
    } else if (typeof toolbar === "string") {
      toolbar = toolbar.split(",");
      if (toolbar.indexOf("myDropdownBlock") === -1) {
        editor.config.set("toolbar", toolbar.join(",") + ",myDropdownBlock");
      }
    } else if (typeof toolbar === "object" && Array.isArray(toolbar.items)) {
      if (toolbar.items.indexOf("myDropdownBlock") === -1) {
        toolbar.items.push("myDropdownBlock");
        editor.config.set("toolbar", toolbar);
      }
    }
  }

  _createDropdownItems() {
    const itemDefinitions = new Collection();

    itemDefinitions.add({
      type: "button",
      model: new Model({
        commandParam: "testClass",
        label: "Test label",
        withText: true,
      }),
    });
    /* ... other items adding ...*/

    return itemDefinitions;
  }
}



The error occurs at the command writer.createPositionAt(blockElement.parent, 0). I have checked that blockElement.parent exists and is not the root of the document, but I still get an error. This is the last version of my code, sorry if it is messy. I tried so many other options before.
The error message is: error CKEditorError: model-writer-insert-forbidden-move & Uncaught CKEditorError: e.getAncestors is not a function from catch(
I would appreciate any help in understanding why this error is occurring and how to fix it. Thank you!
Here is my other attempt to resolve this issue. It's working almost as expected. It creates div with class around the selection, but it does not get rid of surrounding :


import { Plugin, Command } from "ckeditor5/src/core";
import { Collection } from "ckeditor5/src/utils";
import { addListToDropdown, createDropdown, Model } from "ckeditor5/src/ui";

class InsertDivCommand extends Command {
  execute({ value }) {
    const editor = this.editor;
    const model = editor.model;

    model.change((writer) => {
      const selection = model.document.selection;

      if (selection.isCollapsed) {
        return;
      }

      const range = selection.getFirstRange();

      if (!range) {
        return;
      }

      const selectedText = Array.from(range.getItems())
        .map((item) => item.data)
        .join("");

      const parentElement = range.start.parent;

      if (!parentElement || parentElement.name !== "paragraph") {
        return;
      }

      const div = writer.createElement("div", { divClass: value });
      const textNode = writer.createText(selectedText);
      writer.append(textNode, div);

      writer.remove(range);
      if (parentElement.positionBefore) {
        writer.insert(div, parentElement.positionBefore);
        writer.remove(parentElement);
      } else {
        writer.insert(div, range.start);
      }

      writer.setSelection(div, "after");
    });
  }

  refresh() {
    const model = this.editor.model;
    const selection = model.document.selection;

    this.isEnabled = !selection.isCollapsed;
  }
}

export default class StyleBlockDropdownPlugin extends Plugin {
  init() {
    const editor = this.editor;
    const t = editor.t;

    editor.model.schema.extend("$block", { allowIn: "div" });
    editor.model.schema.register("div", {
      isBlock: true,
      allowWhere: "$block",
      allowContentOf: "$block",
    });
    editor.model.schema.extend("paragraph", { allowIn: "div" });
    editor.model.schema.extend("paragraph", { allowChildren: ["div"] });
    editor.model.schema.extend("$root", { allowIn: "div" });
    editor.conversion.for("upcast").elementToElement({
      view: "div",
      model: "div",
    });
    editor.conversion.for("dataDowncast").elementToElement({
      model: "div",
      view: (modelElement, { writer }) => {
        return writer.createContainerElement("div", {
          class: modelElement.getAttribute("divClass"),
        });
      },
    });

    editor.conversion.for("editingDowncast").elementToElement({
      model: "div",
      view: (modelElement, { writer }) => {
        return writer.createContainerElement("div", {
          class: modelElement.getAttribute("divClass"),
        });
      },
    });

    editor.commands.add("insertDiv", new InsertDivCommand(editor));

    editor.ui.componentFactory.add("myDropdownBlock", (locale) => {
      const dropdownView = createDropdown(locale);

      addListToDropdown(dropdownView, this._createDropdownItems());

      dropdownView.buttonView.set({
        label: t("Style blokowe"),
        tooltip: true,
        withText: true,
      });

      this.listenTo(dropdownView, "execute", (evt) => {
        editor.execute("insertDiv", { value: evt.source.commandParam });
        editor.editing.view.focus();
      });

      return dropdownView;
    });

    let toolbar = editor.config.get("toolbar");

    if (Array.isArray(toolbar)) {
      if (toolbar.indexOf("myDropdownBlock") === -1) {
        editor.config.set("toolbar", [...toolbar, "myDropdownBlock"]);
      }
    } else if (typeof toolbar === "string") {
      toolbar = toolbar.split(",");
      if (toolbar.indexOf("myDropdownBlock") === -1) {
        editor.config.set("toolbar", toolbar.join(",") + ",myDropdownBlock");
      }
    } else if (typeof toolbar === "object" && Array.isArray(toolbar.items)) {
      if (toolbar.items.indexOf("myDropdownBlock") === -1) {
        toolbar.items.push("myDropdownBlock");
        editor.config.set("toolbar", toolbar);
      }
    }
  }

  _createDropdownItems() {
    const itemDefinitions = new Collection();

    itemDefinitions.add({
      type: "button",
      model: new Model({
        commandParam: "test-class",
        label: "Test Label",
        withText: true,
      }),
    });
    /* more items adding... */

    return itemDefinitions;
  }
}



